# nth derivative of $\frac{1-\cosh(x) }{x}$ at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

After some work I know that $f$ is infinitely differentiable for $x \neq 0$ and, to guarantee continuity, $f(0)=0$. If $f^{n}(x) = - \frac{\cosh(x) +nf^{n-1}(x)}{x}$ for $n$ even ($n > 0$) and $f^{n}(x) = - \frac{\sinh(x) +nf^{n-1}(x)}{x}$ for $n$ odd. Can I assure that there exist $f^{n}(0)$ for all $n$?.

My attemp was to evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} - \frac{\cosh(x) +nf^{n-1}(x)}{x}$. By L'Hopital rule,  if $f^{k} (0)=0$ for $k$ even and $f^{k} =- \frac{1}{k+1} $ for $k$ odd for all $k <n$, then $f^{n} (0)=0$ if $n$ even and $f^{n} =- \frac{1}{n+1} $ if $n$ odd. I believe that I'm finding $f^{n}(0)$ if it exists, but not guaranteeing that it does.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Use the Taylor series of $\cosh(x)$ built around $x=0$
$$\cosh(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ 
$$\frac{1-\cosh(x) }{x}=-\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$$